# Duplication vertex lighting/color

Tags: lighting, vertex-colors

I'm wondering if it is possible to copy vertex lighting from one object to another, similar but different from default one. Here is screen showing what I really want to do ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ9V6.png ) - make every selected place the same dark. I can't do it manually with vertex painting and brush tools because any change is very visible, I want to avoid it. So is it possible and if is how can I apply it?

Thank you in advance for response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using data transfer modifier. Vertex Color is in **Face Corner Data**. If Your objects have same topology, the best setting of matching vertex is **Topology**, otherwise try **nearest corner and best matching normal**:

[image]